# Rails loop not completing action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a weird problem here, i have two model actions here. One is meant to create price record for new users and the other for all already existing users as show here;

```
   def self.initialize_price(user_id)
      prices = InitialPrice.all
      prices.each do |price|
         user_price = Price.new(country: "#{price.country}", network: "#{price.network}", 
                              price_eur: price.price_eur, price_ugx: price.price_ugx, 
                              price_kes: price.price_kes, price_tzs: price.price_tzs,
                              price_usd: price.price_usd, user_id: user_id, prefix: "#{price.prefix}")
         user_price.save
      end
   end

   def self.update_user_prices      
      users = User.all
      users.each do |user|
         Price.initialize_price(user.id)
      end
   end
```

However, the second action when called in the console as

> Price.update_user_prices

It all creates records for only the first user with

> user_id = 1

and skips the others. why?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I think your methods are bloated, and is probably the reason why you've got your error

Looking at your code, I'd use a [`after_create`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) callback in the `User` model

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_create :initialize_price

    def initialize_price
        InitialPrice.each do |price|
            Price.create({country: price.country, network: price.network, 
                          price_eur: price.price_eur, price_ugx: price.price_ugx, 
                          price_kes: price.price_kes, price_tzs: price.price_tzs,
                          price_usd: price.price_usd, user_id: id, prefix: price.prefix})
        end
    end

end
```

I'd try my hardest to [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) up the code as much as possible. You're basically replicating yourself every time you include those local prices. I'd dry it up by changing prices table to handle currency rates for the prices or something

---

**More**

Something that will benefit you will be [instance methods & class methods](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/)

- Instance methods run on an instance of an object - `@user.instance_method`
- Class methods *create* an instance of an object - `User.class_method`

---

**Methods**

I think your problem is you're using `class methods` both times, when I'd use an `instance method` for `initialize_price` method, like this:

```
   #app/models/user.rb #-> User.update_prices
   def self.update_prices      
      self.all.each do |user|
         user.initialize_price
      end
   end  

   #app/models/user.rb # -> @user = User.find(15) @user.initialize_price
   def initialize_price
      prices = InitialPrice.all
      prices.each do |price|
         user_price = Price.new(country: "#{price.country}", network: "#{price.network}", 
                              price_eur: price.price_eur, price_ugx: price.price_ugx, 
                              price_kes: price.price_kes, price_tzs: price.price_tzs,
                              price_usd: price.price_usd, user_id: user_id, prefix: "#{price.prefix}")
      end
      update_attributes(price: price)
   end
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try and go through everything and update my code.. I wrote it in one those nights u just wake up and write and after it works, you improve. Thank you

Comment: No problem - hope it helps somewhat!